# ASP.NET : use the Text property as selector to jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to bind an ASP.NET button based on the Text property to a jQuery Event handler?

For example, if I have these buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" class="btn btn-info" Text="Start" />
<asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger" Text="Stop" />
```

How do I fire the javascript function based on the text rather than the ID of the buttons?

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnStart", function () { 
  Clock.start(); 
});
```

What do I write where the question marks are?

```
$("body").on("click", "???", function () { 
  Clock.start(); 
});
```

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Im creating a stopwatch that will need some start/stop/pause/resume functionality based on what the user do at the time.

Comment: so you're changing the text on the buttons if they click on them?

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. But I have to change the text if some other event happens aswell.

Comment: Use `class` instead and add/remove classes to the button along with changing the text.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It works as I want it to do!

Comment: For future questions make sure to get the full context of your problem :-) happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% Agreed with Mike. Add different class on each and bind click event on it.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-start" Text="Start" />
<asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-stop" Text="Stop" />

$("body").on("click", ".btn-start", function () { 
  Clock.start(); 
});

$("body").on("click", ".btn-stop", function () { 
  Clock.stop(); 
});
```